# Entity framework not all property load

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my code Entity Framework load only one navigation property

```cs
//Model
public class MemorialData
{
    public MemorialData()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Memorial Memorial { get; set; }
    public Guid MemorialId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserData Author { get; set; }
    public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult AddData(MemorialData model)
{
    MemorialData md = db.MemorialDatas.Find(model.Id);
    if (md == null)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("md == null Creating");
        md = new MemorialData();
        md.MemorialId = model.MemorialId;
        //md.Memorial = db.Memorials.Find(model.MemorialId);
        md.Data = model.Data;
        md.AuthorId = db.CurrentUser.Id;
        db.MemorialDatas.Add(md);
    }
    else
    {
        md.Data = model.Data;
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Saving " + md.Id);
    db.SaveChanges();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Load " + md.Id);
    md = db.MemorialDatas.Find(md.Id);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AuthorId " + md.AuthorId);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Author is NULL? " + (md.Author == null));
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MemorialId " + md.MemorialId);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Memorial is NULL? " + (md.Memorial == null));
}
```

Debug output

*md == null Creating*

*Saving 1b21f49f-749d-4cd3-8c3f-1f128ce67f6f*

*Load 1b21f49f-749d-4cd3-8c3f-1f128ce67f6f*

*AuthorId 7b1fc9c4-4930-45be-9196-44b3f49e6770*

**Author is NULL? False**

*MemorialId a813a8f4-409b-4c97-8d2d-cb19aff267bb*

**Memorial is NULL? True ???**

**Why Memorial is null but Author not null?**

**Where to find the cause of the error?**

P.S.

If uncomment //md.Memorial = db.Memorials.Find(model.MemorialId);

**Memorial is NULL? False ???**

Comment: Are you sure that you have memorial with given id?

Comment: Yes, change code in post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `db.CurrentUser` is a `User` entity. Apparently in your `AddData` method this entity is already loaded because you are using:

```
md.AuthorId = db.CurrentUser.Id;
```

(If not, you would get a `NullReferenceException`.)

When you set the `AuthorId` EF will set the `Author` navigation property as well when `DetectChanges` is called (happens inside of `db.MemorialDatas.Add`) because the `Author` (=`db.CurrentUser`) is in memory and probably attached to the context.

The `Memorial` entity is not loaded, you seem to have only the `model.MemorialId` available.

Your test to write and read the `MemorialData` happens in the same context and ...

```
md = db.MemorialDatas.Find(md.Id);
```

...doesn't run a database query because you have added it to the context before, hence `Find` can return it from memory with `md.Author` being set.

`md.Memorial` is not set and when you access it EF won't run a lazy loading query because you didn't create a dynamic proxy but just a plain Entity with `md = new MemorialData()`.

In order to fix the problem and to enable lazy loading so that `md.Memorial` can be loaded from the database you must create a dynamic proxy (instead of `md = new MemorialData();`):

```
md = db.MemorialDatas.Create();
```

Comment: Yes **md = db.MemorialDatas.Create();** is solution